# How to calculate L12W and L12WYAG in Power BI (DAX)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find out sales for Last 12 weeks(L12W) and the Last 12 weeks Year ago(L12 YAG).The tables involved are  date table and another table with a variable Dollar value.
This is the measure I created for L12 and L12YAG.

```
L12W $ = CALCULATE([Cons $],DATESINPERIOD('Date Table'[Date],LASTDATE('Date Table'[Date]),-84,day))
L12W YAG = calculate(calculate([Cons $],datesinperiod('Date Table'[Date],lastdate('Date Table'[Date]),-84,day)),dateadd('Date Table'[Date],-364,day))
```

L12 seems to calculate correctly, however L12YAG is incorrect. I can say that because I am also doing the calculations for L28YAG, L52YAG. All of these YAG's are adding to the same number.

Can someone please suggest changes? Tried SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: this might help https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/

Answer (score 0):

This formula works. My report had a filter set to 2020 and 2021. I deleted the filter and got the correct values for 12W YAG.